# echo variable with variable in included.php

Tags: php, variables, include, echo

I have two php files.
One is action.php and the other is include.php

I need to echo variable form include.php in my other scripts.

Basically in include.php there are this variables

```
     $id= $web_id;
     $start = "Hello, ";
     $end = "works.";
```

In my action.php I have this variables

```
     $web_id = "testing echo from variable in include.php";

     echo $start; // variable is in include.php
     echo $id; //variable is in include.php
     echo $end; //variable is in include.php
```

Result is

```
     Hello, works.
```

Wham I am trying to achieve is

```
     Hello, testing echo from variable in include.php works.
```

This syntax echos only empty value for $id.
What is the right syntax for echoing variable with variable in included file?

Comment: In 1st file you are allocating $web_id to $id that time $web_id is empty. So that empty value stored into the $id & $id will print empty.. You are setting $web_id after the $id allocation that`s why $id not updated with new $web_id. For your expected output you have to add $id=$web_id after $web_id = 'data';

Comment: You need to set your `$web_id` before you do your include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `$web_id` variable before you do your include. Take a look at this example:

#### action.php

```
$web_id = 'this'.
include 'include.php';

echo $start . $id . $end;
```

#### include.php

```
$id = $web_id;
$start = 'Hello ';
$end = ' works.';
```